# Как преобразовать массив vector<int> в матрицу vector<vector<int>>?

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть цикл, преобразующий квадратную матрицу в плоский (одномерный) массив:

```cpp
int n = 5; //для примера
vector<vector<int>> p1(n,vector<int>(n)); //наша матрица
// забиваем матрицу значениями

vector<int> p1_flat; //наш плоский массив
p1_flat.reserve(n * n);

for (auto const &row : p1)
    copy(row.begin(), row.end(), back_inserter(p1_flat));
```

А как сделать наоборот?
Приветствуется хороший вариант с точки зрения производительности, потому что работаю с матрицами большого размера.

Comment: для  представления матрицы, использование вектора,  не самое оптимальное решение...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, да, сейчас я в курсе, но когда начинал реализовывать свою задачу, думал, раз уж пишу на с++, то и писать надо в стиле с++, а не си

Comment: а я и не говорю про стиль си.  Есть std::array, а  std::valarray еще лучше

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, чем они лучше? Я думал, вы говорите про производительность

Comment: да, std::valarray  например может представить  любые свои срезы и имеет много полезных других функциональностей, которые избавят еще и от лишнеггоо кода, кроме того ничего не нужно  копировать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 5;
    vector<int> p1_flat;
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; ++i) p1_flat.push_back(i);

    vector<vector<int>> p1(n,vector<int>(n));

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        copy_n(p1_flat.begin()+i*n,n,p1[i].begin());

    for(auto a: p1)
    {
        for(auto b: a) cout << setw(2) << b << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/lih4aN

Answer (score 3):

так

```
for(int i = 0, row = 0; i < p1_flat.size(); i += n, row++) {
    copy_n(p1_flat.begin() + i, n, p1[row].begin());
}
```

Comment: спасибо, у вас тоже хороший вариант, +1 поставил. Просто у Harry чуть проще цикл